# T is a compact operator implies $\langle T(u_n) , u_n \rangle$ converges to 0

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I try to show : $T$ is a compact operator implies $\langle T(u_n) , u_n \rangle$ converges to 0 for every othonormal sequence $\{u_n\}_n$ in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. I already proved something quit similar to the converse of this proposition, but I don't know how to start here. Thank you

Comment: $Tu_{n_k}\to v$ gives $\langle Tu_{n_k}, u_{n_k} \rangle \to 0$ since $ \langle v, u_n \rangle \to 0$. Now argue with subsequences.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy why $\langle v,un \rangle →0 $ ?

Answer (score 0):

$T(\overline{B(0,1)})$ is relatively compact and contains $(T(e_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite number of elements $y_1,...,y_N$ such that $T(\overline{B(0,1)})\subset \cup_{i=1}^N B(y_i,\epsilon)$. We have for each $n$,

$$|\langle T(e_n),e_n\rangle|\leq|\langle T(e_n)-y_i,e_n\rangle|+|\langle y_i,e_n\rangle|.$$
By $T(\overline{B(0,1)})\subset \cup_{i=1}^N B(y_i,\epsilon)$, there is a $j$ such that:

$$|\langle T(e_n),e_n\rangle|\leq \epsilon+ |\langle y_j,e_n\rangle|\leq \epsilon+\max_{i=1,...,N} |\langle y_i,e_n\rangle|.$$

The previous innequality works for all $n$. Using that $\lim_n |\langle y_i,e_n\rangle|=0$ (Bessel's inequality) for each $i=1,...,N$, we conclude,

$$\limsup_n|\langle T(e_n),e_n\rangle|\leq\epsilon.$$